# Where is UNS_32 defined?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm, gnu-arm

I'm using Doxygen on a client's source code and Doxygen can't find a symbol `UNS_32`.

The client's code compiles without errors using the GNU ARM compiler.

I have searched the client's code base and can't find the definition of `UNS_32`.

I searched the GNU ARM source code tree and can't find it either.

So, where is the symbol `UNS_32` defined?

*Note:  I'm not looking for the meaning.  I want the definition so I can put it in my Doxygen configuration file. *

Example usage:

```
void lpc_heap_init (void *base_addr, UNS_32 heap_size);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in `lpc_types.h`

http://code.google.com/p/32bitmicro/source/browse/trunk/src/nxp/lpc17xx/LPC1700CMSIS/Drivers/include/lpc_types.h?spec=svn226&r=226

```
/** SMA type for 32 bit unsigned value */
typedef uint32_t UNS_32;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also to search and headers in paths specified to the compiler with -I options.  You can similarly specify these in Doxygen.

My preferred approach is to use Visual Studio, create a "Makefile Project", add the sources and copy all the project's command line defined macros and include paths to the project settings, then let the Intellisense simplify code navigation  - it is a simple case of right-clicking the symbol, and selecting "Goto Definition", or using the "Code Definition" window which shows the defining source for any symbol you place the cursor on.  You could even set up the project to actiually build the code too.